# 404 error on Woocommerce pages because of permalink

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a wordpress website (WP version 5.2.2). It's an online shop. Wordpress dashboard and the main page are ok. But we keep getting 404 error on product pages. We can fix it by saving Permalink settings. However after a while it happens again. 
I would really appreciate it if someone could help me fix this problem.

Updated all plugins and restarted Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

disable all plugins except woocommerce and check if it's happening again, try changing themes also, seems theme or plugin issue.

Answer (score 0):

check plugins/theme for conflicts. Given the permalinks work with a different base, this is almost certainly a conflict rather than a WC bug. It could be a plugin, conflicting post type, even a page/post with the same name 'product'.